# Como chamar uma função após o usuário soltar o clique do mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em uma página existe um elemento que o usuário pode arrastar com o mouse, gostaria de chamar uma função após o usuário soltar esse elemento (quando soltar o clique do mouse). Como fazer isso sem ter como referência o elemento, apenas reconhecendo que o botão do mouse deixou de ser pressionado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mouseup()

O evento é disparado quando o botão do mouse é solto. Note que a mensagem só é exibida quando o botão do mouse (qualquer um) é solto.

Exemplo de uso do mouseup

```
$(function(){
    $("#div1").mouseup(function(){
        alert("O botao foi solto.")
    });
});
```